# Sorting p-dataTable not working when p-column uses ng-template

Tags: angular, angular-template, primeng-datatable

I'm trying to sort a column that has template. My understing is that when a column uses a template, the sorting should be done by responding to the sorting event.

```
<p-column field="activityName" [sortable]="true" (onSort)="onNameSorting($event)">
  <ng-template let-col let-activity="rowData" pTemplate="body">
   //..
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

However, when I put a breakpoint in the event handler, nothing is happening. Am I missing something?

```
onNameSorting(e){
  debugger;       //--> the breakpoint is not being hit
  //...
}
```

Thanks for helping

## Edit

The breakpoint is being hit, the sorting is being performed. Yet no change is being reflected in the *dataTable*.

```
onNameSorting(e, dt){
  debugger;              //This break point is being hit now.
  if(!!e.order && e.order > 0){
     this.filteredItems = this.filteredItems
        .sort((a, b) => (a.activityName < b.activityName) ? -1 : 1);
  }else{
     this.filteredItems = this.filteredItems
        .sort((a, b) => (a.activityName > b.activityName) ? -1 : 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the old prime data-table. In that version there was no `(onSort)="onNameSorting($event)"` binding to the `p-column`. Move that to the `p-dataTable`

Ex:-

```html
<p-dataTable scrollable="true" [value]="_rowList" [selectionMode]="selectionMode"
             [responsive]="true" (selectionChange)="rowSelectionChange($event)"
             (click)="rowSingleClick($event)" (dblclick)="rowDoubleClick($event)" [(selection)]="_selectedEntity"
<!-- refer to the next line, above lines are bunch of attributes -->
             (onSort)="sortData($event, dt)"[sortField]="sortField" [sortOrder]="sortOrder" #dt>
<p-column field="activityName">
  <ng-template let-col let-activity="rowData" pTemplate="body">
   //..
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Suggestion: They have launched the new PrimeNg Turbo [table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table). Its much easier and faster.

Comment: we're still using the old dataTable., and that's not my decision Let's hope that your solution works as I need to fix the same exact issue on so many pages.

Comment: the breakpoint and the sorting is being done in the event handler, but the `dataTable` is not reflecting the sorting. Please see the update.

Comment: never mind. I needed to add `this.filteredItems = [...this.filteredItems]` for the dataTable to detect the change.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I hope you got it to working.